# Proof there exists a point $O$ such $|AO|\le p,|BO|\le q,|CO|\le r$

Tags: geometry

> Give the postive numbers $p=\dfrac{y+z-x}{\sqrt{3}},q=\dfrac{z+x-y}{\sqrt{3}},r=\dfrac{x+y-z}{\sqrt{3}}$,in $\Delta ABC$, where $|AB|=z,|BC|=x,|AC|=y$,and $G$ is centroids, I have prove following inequality:
>   $$AG^2+BG^2+CG^2\le p^2+q^2+r^2$$
>
> show that:  there exists  a ponit $O$(in$\Delta ABC$) such
>   $$|AO|\le p,|BO|\le q,|CO|\le r$$

Maybe proof by contradiction,
what approaches do you think, I could take to solving the next step

Comment: Use $OA^2+OB^2+OC^2=GA^2+GB^2+GC^2+3OG^2$

Comment: Hello,Is $GC^2$,then how to explain?

Comment: $OA^2+OB^2+OC^2\leq (p^2+OG^2)+(q^2+OG^2)+(r^2+OG^2)$ ,

Comment: You only have to show there can exist such a point, it may not always be true.

Comment: current question is not difficult, you just find O on AG at some position,use cos,, it should be easy to show O satisfy the condition. The real problem behind is LHS is min ,all points except G are bigger.

Comment: @chenbai,can you post your solution? because Now I can't understand

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/medians.shtml

Comment: I can't open your links

Answer (score 0):

If $p,q,r$ has no constrain, for example, $p+q> AB$, in case $p+q<AB$ ,then there is no such point $O$ inside $ABC$ which can satisfy $AO+BO <AB $. it is trivial.

If $p+q>AB, p+r>AC,q+r>BC$, then the problem becomes find min of$AO^2+BO^2+CO^2$

let $A(x_A,y_A),B(x_B,y_B),C(x_C,y_C),O(x,y)$, list $AO^2+BO^2+CO^2$, you should be able to find min will be got when $O=G$

Comment: Hello,Nice, In fact my problem is $p=\dfrac{y+z-x}{\sqrt{3}},q=\dfrac{z+x-y}{\sqrt{3}},r=\dfrac{x+y-z}{\sqrt{3}}$,where $|BC|=x,|AC|=y,|AB|=z$,so $p+q>|AB|,p+r>|AC|,q+r>|BC|$, But why this problem becoms find the min of $AO^2+BO^2+CO^2?$

Comment: the condition you give which means O can be any point inside ABC, so $GA^2+GB^2+GC^2$ has to be min.of course, you may need to add some explanation for this, for example ,when you take $BO=q,CO=r,$ then $AO \le p$.draw two circles will make it very clear.